# In Python, how do you use decimal module in a script rather than the interpreter?

Tags: python, decimal

I'm using Python 2.5.4 and trying to use the decimal module. When I use it in the interpreter, I don't have a problem.  For example, this works:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> Decimal('1.2')+ Decimal('2.3')
Decimal("3.5")
```

But, when I put the following code:

```
from decimal import *
print Decimal('1.2')+Decimal('2.3')
```

in a separate file (called decimal.py) and run it as a module, the interpreter complains:

> NameError: name 'Decimal' is not defined

I also tried putting this code in a separate file:

```
import decimal
print decimal.Decimal('1.2')+decimal.Decimal('2.3')
```

When I run it as a module, the interpreter says:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Decimal'

What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure that the script is being run with the same Python version as your interactive interpreter? Try putting in a `print sys.version` if you want to check.

Comment: Perhaps you have created a file called `decimal.py` that is being imported instead of Python's builtin one

Comment: I tried running in my script:
import sys
print sys.version

and yes, the interpreter does say that it is the same version.  I think I only have one version installed on my computer.

Comment: I guess try adding `print dir(decimal)` after `import decimal` and check what functions are exposed.

Comment: It works. @gnibbler: Yes, my script was on a file named decimal.py and this was the problem.  To fix it, i did a "save as" to my file and named it a different name, and then deleted the compiled "decimal" file and "decimal.py".  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: @jack, gnibbler's answer is correct. Please mark it as such. You just left out decimal. in the second term of the print statement. This is a case of mixed metaphors. When you use "import ModuleName", you must prefix ModuleName. to the function name; when you use "from ModuleName import *", you do not prefix the ModuleName.

Comment: @jack, check out section 6.1.2 "The Module Search Path" of the Python Tutorial here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: @Geoffrey: gnibbler's *comment* is correct, while it is DasIch's answer that should be marked.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I originally had two bugs in my program.  The first bug was a typo in which I put "print decimal.Decimal('1.2')+Decimal('2.3')" instead of "print decimal.Decimal('1.2')+decimal.Decimal('2.3')". I've since edited my post to reflect this so that future readers don't have to address this problem.  The second bug, which was the main problem was that I had named my script "decimal.py" which gnibbler pointed out in a comment above and Daslch posted in an answer below, which I have now marked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You named your script decimal.py, as the directory the script is in is the first in the path the modules are looked up your script is found and imported. You don't have anything named Decimal in your module which causes this exception to be raised.

To solve this problem simply rename the script, as long as you are just playing around something like foo.py, bar.py, baz.py, spam.py or eggs.py is a good choice for a name.

Comment: +1 Although the OP hasn't answered yet, my money is on this too. This is an issue that happens too often.

Comment: Thank you gnibbler and Daslch.

Answer (score 14):

This works fine as is for me on Python 2.5.2

```
from decimal import *
print Decimal('1.2')+Decimal('2.3')
```

I would encourage you to specify what you want to use from decimal

```
from decimal import Decimal
print Decimal('1.2')+Decimal('2.3')
```

In your other example you should use

```
import decimal
print decimal.Decimal('1.2')+decimal.Decimal('2.3')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo.  I ran: 
import decimal
print decimal.Decimal('1.2')+decimal.Decimal('2.3')
and still got the error of AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Decimal'

Comment: I've edited my post that originally read 
"import decimal
print decimal.Decimal('1.2')+Decimal('2.3')" 

to now read:

"import decimal
print decimal.Decimal('1.2')+decimal.Decimal('2.3')"